# How to have a floating form stay above a maximized floating form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

[Please see here the preferred position of forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92GhG.png)

Is it possible to have a floating window [3] above a maximized pop window [2]? The requirement is to have the floating window as a note-taking form that should be setting above the main floating window(maximized).

1. Note-taking form [3] should still be visible to the users even if the cursor is moved to the main maximized form [2]. By default, when the cursor is moved to main form, note-taking forms moves to the back of the main window. I want to override that and stick the note-taking form above all forms.
2. Note-taking form [3] should only be hidden if manually closed by the user.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: You can show 3rd form above 2nd form but then can't focus any control of 2nd form or can't edit data to 2nd form. You can work with 3rd form.

Comment: Make form 2 a normal, maximised form. Then focusing on form 2 will leave form 3 in front.

Comment: @Gustav yes I already tried this too. But for some important reason, my client would like the main window a pop-up form to occupy the entire screen without the MS Access ribbon showing on the top.

Comment: Well, he/she may wish so, but not all wishes come through ...

Answer (score 0):

If you launch that floating form as a popup? Then it will remain on top - and do so at all times.

So, popup forms are designed for exactly your use case - it is a form that floats on top of existing forms - can remain open, and allows focus to change between the main (say maximized form) and this popup form.

in fact, on a duel monitor, the popup form can be dragged off screen to the 2nd monitor if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @Albert. The challenge is our app is stored in a virtual cloud desktop which most of the users only have 1 screen for it. And both this floating form and the main window are pop-up forms. So when window selection is changed to the main window the floating form will go to the back.

Comment: And why is the main screen a popup? It should NEVER be as such.